# How do I call the Apple App Store servers from a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, app-store, in-app-purchase

I'm looking into building a server to distribute our content and keeping track of available products, subscriptions and what not. My first approach is Rails3 based, but I'm a little concerned with how I would communicate with the App Store. The receipt sent from the device has to be confirmed by the server with the App Store. So far I can only find a objective-c library to talk to the App Store.

Is it possible to use that objective-c library in a rails app? Have I actually missed that Apple has a REST API for their App Store?

Answer (score 2):

They sure do: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid I don't need a iTunes API, I'm looking to integrate with the App Store and the in-app purchase functionality.

Comment: From the link: "The Search API allows you to place search fields in your website to search for content within the iTunes Store, App Store, iBooks Store and Mac App Store." This is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should always validate the App Store receipts using your server and not from your device. You should check out this ruby gem that makes it really easy to validate receipts on the server: https://github.com/gabrielgarza/monza